# Count non-blank cells in Excel rows (not using VBA)

Tags: excel, cells

I have multiple rows in excel workbooks. Rows in the workbook are filled in with values derived from formulae. Data in these cells is populated (from underlying tables) when I select certain input combinations in the workbook. The Rows in workbook have `0` (zero), `-` (dash), or non-zero values. I want to count the cells which have non-zero values and `0` (zero). `-` (dash) should not be counted.

I tried `countif` but did not work. (`countif(range,"-")` or `countif(range,0)`, etc.)
I also tried `=COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)` and that did not work, either.

As the cells are filled with formulae, correct results are not being shown.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i tried this formulae and it worked. `=COUNTA(A1:A9) - COUNTIF(A1:A9,"-")`. does your data have any other characters/ empty spaces??

Comment: Are you using currency formatting?

Comment: All the cells are filled in with formulae/vlookup. No currency format is used. No empty spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **COUNTIFS function** to find your solution:

> =COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<>-",A1:A4,"<>0")

[image]

If you are using currency formatting usually numbers that are between 0.099 and -0.099 will be reflected as zero and zeros will be reflected as dashes, therefore two **COUNTIF functions** will need to be used in order to capture this:

> =COUNTIF(A1:A4,">=0.01")+COUNTIF(A1:A4,"<=-0.01")

Comment: This did not work. Pl note that the values in the worksheet are derived from lookup/formulae. Each cell is filled with formula. Irrespective of value 0 or - or non-zero, there is a formula in the cell. I have 12 columns and am getting count as 12 irrespective of the value.

Comment: Can you share input examples e.g. which formulas you are using?

Comment: N1N2N3N4N5N6N7N8N9N10N11N12
 (0) (0) (0) (14) (14) (14) (14) (14) (14) (14) (14) (14)
 #N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A#N/A

 Formula in each cell:
 =ROUND(INDEX(INDIRECT(A$3&A$2),MATCH($C$4&"XYZ"&$C$2&$C$3&$D3&$A3,INDIRECT(A$3&"!A:A"),0)),0)

 N1 to N12 are columns
 The first row is values displayed (after copy/paste special)
 The second row has formulae and results not displayed due to incorrect lookup. The actual sheets does have have values derived from formulae.

 Thanks!!